# Association properties not loading on entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have three related entities, best described by this diagram:

[alt text http://thehashtable.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/Enttities.png](http://thehashtable.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/Enttities.png)

When I load a user, using the following code, the `User` object is loaded, i.e. not null, but the `Role` and `Department` properties on the `User` object are null, despite User database record having valid FK values for these associations.

```
using (var productionEntities = new ProductionEntities())
{
    var userName = GetUserName();
    User u = (from usr in productionEntities.UserSet
              where usr.UserName == userName
              select usr).FirstOrDefault();
    if (u == null)
    {
        throw new KpiSecurityException("No local database entry found for user.") { UserName = userName };
    }
    return u.Department.DeptName;
}
```

**ASIDE:**  I went through this whole mission just because the ASP.NET MembershipProvider doesn't support user 'metadata' like department, and I would have had to use the ProfileProvider as well, at the cost of immense DB bloat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only need the department name, just [project](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/12/31/38500/) that out; this way you query the DB only once:

```
using (var productionEntities = new ProductionEntities())
{
    var userName = GetUserName();
    var u  = (from usr in productionEntities.UserSet
              where usr.UserName == userName
              select new
              {
                  DeptName = usr.Department.DeptName
              }).FirstOrDefault();
    if (u == null)
    {
        throw new KpiSecurityException("No local database entry found for user.") { UserName = userName };
    }
    return u.DeptName;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you must explicitly load this properties

```
User u = (from usr in productionEntities.UserSet
          where usr.UserName == userName
          select usr).FirstOrDefault();

if (u == null)
{
        throw new KpiSecurityException("No local database entry found for user.") { UserName = userName };
}

if (!u.RoleReference.IsLoaded)
{ u.RoleReference.Load(); }

if (!u.DeparmentReference.IsLoaded)
{ u.DeparmentReference.Load(); }
```

or include this entities in your query

```
User u = (from usr in productionEntities.UserSet.Include("Role").Include("Department")
          where usr.UserName == userName
          select usr).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: That will result in three DB queries; only one is needed.

Comment: +1 for teaching me the IsLoaded and Load() members.  I knew there was something like that, but I just didn't know where to look for it.

Comment: Ishtar, `Load()` generates too many queries, and `Include` generates overly complicated queries. Either way, you're making the DB server work harder than necessary to return one single field.

Comment: Craig: But the question was about loading referenced properties, not about selecting one single field. And in LINQ to Entities isn't imho other right way to do this. Using stored procedures for listing and selecting would be counter-productive.

Comment: His method returns one field. Why select anything else. Nobody suggested stored procs; that would be a waste of effort. L2E already handles this fine. I don't know why you'd want to execute a query (or queries!) which return dozens of properties from multiple objects when you only need one value returned from the method.